# Conditionally remove lines between two patterns in a file

Tags: python, perl, vim, awk, sed

Input file :

```
<Chunk of text>
PATTERN1
ABC
EFG
HIJ
PATTERN2
KLM
NOP
PATTERN3
<Chunk of text>
```

Output File :

```
<Chunk of text> 
<Chunk of text>
```

How to remove the lines between PATTERN 1 and PATTERN 3 of a file(inclusive) only if there is  PATTERN2 between them

Comment: It's easy if the problem is defined clearly. What about `PATTERN1 ... PATTERN1 ... PATTERN2 ... PATTERN1 ... PATTERN3 ... PATTERN2 ... PATTERN3` - what should be removed then? Please show the code/regex you've written so far, and explain how it's not working as intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import sys,re
flaG,deletE,storE = False,False,""
for linE in open(sys.argv[1]):
    if re.search('pattern1',linE): 
        flaG = True
        print storE
        storE = linE
        continue
    if flaG :
        storE += linE
        if re.search('pattern2',linE): deletE = True
        if re.search('pattern3',linE) :
            if not deletE : print storE
            storE = ''
            flaG = False
            deletE = False
    else : print linE,
print storE
```

Answer (score 0):

The tool for the job here is probably the range operator - tests if you're currently between two patterns (or line numbers).

- Test if you are between PATTERN1 and PATTERN3.
- Store in a buffer
- when you hit "PATTERN3" then check if you saw a PATTERN2, and either print or discard your buffer.

E.g.:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;


my @buffer; 
my $found = 0; 
while ( <DATA>) {
   #check we are between patterns
   if ( m/PATTERN1/ .. m/PATTERN3/ ) {
      #test if pattern 2 is in this chunk. 
      if ( m/PATTERN2/ ) { $found++; }
      #stash this line
      push @buffer, $_; 
   }
   else {
       #outside pattern1..pattern3
       #do we have a pending buffer? (e.g. just finished)
       if ( @buffer ) { 
          #print if we didn't see a pattern 2
          if ( not $found ) { print @buffer }
          #reset buffer and count of pattern 2. 
          $found = 0;
          @buffer = ();
       }
       #print current line. 
       print; 
   }
}

__DATA__
<Chunk of text>
PATTERN1
ABC
EFG
HIJ
PATTERN2
KLM
NOP
PATTERN3
<Chunk of text>
```